# (In WordPress) How do you pass URL parameters further downstream?

Tags: wordpress, parameter-passing, query-string

I'm running a pest control AdWords campaign.

When people click on an ad and get to my main page, the url has a query string that has the service and the town name

It'll be like pestcontrol.com/pestcontrol?service=roaches&town=Beverly

It's important because I draw from this query string to populate the page heading "Looking for [service] in [town]?"

On my main page, they have to choose the pest that they're having trouble with.

Let's say they pick rodents - it'll send them to the rodent page

But I'll lose the query string...

How can I keep the query string so that the next page can be personalized as well?

Is there some way to write a link so it keeps the current query string?

I'm a noob and I'm new to Wordpress and web dev in general so any help is appreciated

Comment: Your form has to include these URL parameters in order to pass them to the next page. The $_GET superglobal is what you're looking for.

Comment: I appreciated the answer but like I said I'm super new to Wordpress and I'm not a dev. I just want to make a link that grabs the current query string and appends it. Something like www.pestcontrol.com/nextpage(copy current querystring here)

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the [$_GET superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) yet? I can understand that you're not very experience when it comes to programming but you have to at least try something on your own. We're very willing to help you improve/fix your code, just not to write it for you.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation and trying to make sense of it. I was hoping I could just write something into a link that took the current query string. Say I'm on example.com/pageone?hi=bye - I was hoping I could make a link like example.com/pagetwo(insert current query string) and end up on example.com/pagetwo?hi=bye

Comment: It looks like the $_GET only gets me the values - I don't need the values. I just need the same query string to pass to the next page in the URL

Comment: If you know which parameters you're going to get, you can build your custom URL using the values from the $_GET superglobal. If you don't know exactly which parameters you'll be receiving, then have a look at `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Be careful though: by carelessly passing URLs parameters to your app you might be opening yourself to at least two different types of attacks: [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).